# Cannot type certain special characters in LinuxMint

Tags: linux, keyboard

I found that in my LinuxMint 13.10, when I wanted to type a `@` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>), the screen displayed `"` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> in windows).

However, the biggest problem is there are no ways to type `|`.

Therefore, I would like to ask how I can change the keyboard settings?

Comment: The question seems to want a @ symbol; this is between the : and ~ symbols on a UK keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the keyboard layout. You can use your desktop environment's settings options for that. For example for Mint 15 Cinnamon you can follow http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=135675 . Please identify the exact Linux Mint desktop environment you are using to help you more if you can not find it.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this answer is late (about 7 years), but even I had the same problem and found the solution and I want to share it so that other who have the same problem might benefit from it.

- Change the keyboard layout from "English (UK)" to "English (US)". This solves the problem.